# Build function is called executed before of dispose when parameter is passed flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

Build function is called executed before of dispose when parameter is passed.
Named route is used.

This is the output of the code

```
I/flutter (12390): called init statment
I/flutter (12390): build context is run
I/flutter (12390): called button function to pop
I/flutter (12390): build context is run
I/flutter (12390): dispose is called
```

Dart code :

```
class ShowProducts extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = '/showProducts';

  @override
  _ShowProductsState createState() => _ShowProductsState();
}

class _ShowProductsState extends State<ShowProducts> {
  PStream _productSallesStream;
  BCategory category;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("called init statment");
    _productSallesStream = ProductSallesStream();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build context is run");
    category = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("called button function to pop");
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
        title: "${category?.name?.firstLetterUpperCase()}".text.make(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print("dispose is called");
    _productSallesStream.dispose();
    
  }
}
```

But without using the ModelRote the life cycle has no problem.

The problem occurs when using ModelRote to get the param

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken. Dispose function always runs at the last and its not a bug. It releases the memory before the widget is cleared. Build Context always runs before the dispose function.

The stages are:

```
1) Create State
2) Mounted
3) initState
4) didChangeDependencies
5) build
6) didUpdateWidget
7) setState
8) deactivate
9) dispose
10) mounted
```

At the last stage 'mounted' , setState cannot be called again.

But in your case, As you have not shared any code of previous activity, i think the build function of previos activity is called

Comment: when i click the navigator pop the build function is executed after it dispose executed .

Comment: when i removed ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments; this statement thir was no build function is executed  when the navigator pop is called

Comment: Using flutter beta